# Scala Existential type weird behavior

Tags: scala, class, inheritance, types, existential-type

I have the following in my REPL:

```
scala> trait T[A]
defined trait T

scala> :kind T[A] forSome {type A}
T[_]'s kind is A

scala> :kind T[_]
T[_]'s kind is A
```

Now when i do:

```
trait e[_] extends T[_]
```

I get

```
error: class type required but T[_] found
```

However the following works:

```
scala> trait e[_] extends T[Int]
defined trait e
```

With

```
scala> :kind T[Int]
T[Int]'s kind is A
```

Why is T[Int] treated differently from T[_], while they are of the same Kind ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not about kind, it's about whether a type is a class type (including traits) or not.

You can write

```
type T <: U
```

for every type `U` but

```
trait T extends U
```

only for a *class type* `U`.

Subtyping and inheritance/subclassing are different.

The type corresponding to a `trait T[A]` is a class type for every type `A`. So `T[Int]` is a class type. (When you write `extends A[B]` it's important that `A` is a class type, `B` can be arbitrary type.)

Existential type (like `T[_]` aka `T[A] forSome {type A}`) is not a class type. (You can also think of `T[_]` as a supertype of all `T[A]`. Actually, `T[_]` is the least upper bound of all `T[A]`).

Comment: Not sure to follow the issue, can you expand please ?

Comment: @MaatDeamon Existential type is not a class type.

Comment: @MaatDeamon And when you write `trait e[_]` it's the same as `trait e[X]`.

Comment: Getting there but just confirming T[Int] is a class type, but T[A] forSome {type A} is not ?

Comment: Yeah i got the difference between call site and definition site, from you last response. Hence i am playing around to test stuff.

Comment: @MaatDeamon Yes, the type corresponding to `trait T[A]` is a class type for every type `A`. So `T[Int]` is a class type. But existential type `T[_]` aka `T[A] forSome {type A}` is not a class type.

Comment: I know it is a bit different but this question is inspired from your example ```trait A[X]
trait B[F[_]]  extends A[F[_]]```. What is the difference ? here in A[F[_]] it is almost the same

Comment: @MaatDeamon When you wtrite `extends A[B]` it's important that `A` is a class type, `B` can be arbitrary type.

Comment: Ok got it. That was a tricky one. Understanding that T[_] is not a class type, but it is actually used for class type where we don't know the entire type. Just because it is used to replace a class type, like in variable declaration, does not make it a class type. Hence can't be extended.

Comment: @MaatDeamon You can also think of `T[_]` as a supertype of all `T[A]` (actually, the least upper bound of all `T[A]`).